# Simple LINQ query to Delete From DataContext Where ID == ID

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am getting the ID of an entry in a database table in my codebehind, and am trying to find a simple LINQ query to delete the entry based on the ID.

Here is what I have:

```
DataContext.Items.DeleteObject((Item)DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.ItemId == selectedId));
```

This gives me a casting error however, and I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this? I've looked at similar questions and every answer I see seems to be more complicated than this should actually be, so any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You currently have an `IQueryable<Item>`, not and Item  - use `Single()` to get the item itself:

```
var item = DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.ItemId == selectedId).Single();
DataContext.Items.DeleteObject(item);
```

This assumes a single matching item (ID as primary key), otherwise consider using `First()` of `FirstOrDefault()` with a null check instead or if you have a collection of item, just delete them in a loop:

```
var items = DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.ItemId == selectedId);
foreach(var item in items)
  DataContext.Items.DeleteObject(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataContext.Items.DeleteObject((Item)DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.ItemId == selectedId).First());
```

Don't forget to prevent error you'll need to ensure that the id you're checking on is of an actual `Item`. Something like this, for example:

```
var item = (Item)DataContext.Items.Where(item => item.ItemId == selectedId).FirstOrDefault();

if (item != null) {
    DataContext.Items.DeleteObject(item);
}
```